# Two UICollectionView inside UITableView not UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I found this post here : http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

But,unfortunately,this doesn't meet my requirement.It was here.

[image]

My flow is similar to the one at App Store.But,What I am gonna do was implementing pull to refresh and pull up to load more at top and button of `UITableView`.

I can include both two `UICollectionView` at the `UITableView`.But,I can't resize second UICollectionView as the data included in its datasource.

Please take a look

[image]

As you can see there was 5 blue block at second uicollection view.But,they are not showing properly.Its there anyway that i can fix my collection view data by resizing uicollectionview?

Because second collection view data will be dynamic as soon as I implement pull to load more below at uitableview cell.So,i disable the second collectionview vertical scrolling.But,I want to appear all the items at second collectionview.

Any Help?I can provide sample if needed.Thanks.

Comment: have you add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to specify size of item?

Comment: Dark gray color is my uicollectionview background.By seeing this,it mean my collection view is not resizing properly.So,I think it's not concerned with UICollectionViewFlowLayoit

Comment: i see, but normally i set my item size inside there. maybe you can check on `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`